# Codeigniter upload_path is empty

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Code:**

```
$config['upload_path']          = './uploads/' . $random;
$config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
echo "[".$this->upload->upload_path."]";
```

**Output:**

```
[]
```

Anyone can please help me why it printing empty? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `echo "[",$this->upload->upload_path,"]";` should be `echo "[" . $this->upload->upload_path . "]";` Instead of comma, need to use `.`

Comment: `echo "[" .$this->upload->upload_path ."]";`  and why don't you use `echo "[". $config['upload_path'] ."]";` and why you added `[]` ? what is need of that?

Comment: Will you show your directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';    
 $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';    
 $this->upload->initialize($config);    
 echo "[".$this->upload->upload_path."]";
```

put

```
$this->load->library('upload');
```

in constructor

Comment: A bit more of explanation would be really helpful to future readers ...